# How to Avoid Click Event Trigger Multiple Times in Android Java code?

Tags: java, android, button, events, onclick

i am trying to add stylus button support into an archived - unmaintained github repository named [gfxtablet](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet)

Basicly it turn android tablets into a digitizer as like wacom.

It has support for drawing, hovering and even stylus pressure. This is great. Only missing piece was stylus button and i cant use it on my tablet samsung galaxy note pro 12.2 which comes with samsung s-pen.

I tried to figure out stylus button event myself by searching online for a long time ( because i am not java nor c programmer.)

Gfxtablet android app communicate with linux with  c programming  application name networktablet.

I read their docs and learn that i could enable stylus button with extra codes.

I could successfully enable stylus button event trigered as right mouse button by adding :

```
if(event.getButtonState() == MotionEvent.BUTTON_SECONDARY)
                {
                    netClient.getQueue().add(new NetEvent(Type.TYPE_BUTTON, nx, ny, (short) 0, 2, true));
                    netClient.getQueue().add(new NetEvent(Type.TYPE_BUTTON, nx, ny, (short)0, 2, false));;

                }
```

inside

```
@Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
...
```

My edit is this :

[image]

Original file is [here ,line 110](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/blob/master/app-android/app/src/main/java/at/bitfire/gfxtablet/CanvasView.java#L110)

i add code above after switch statement.

it works but the problem is , code fired multiple events and as a result it behave as like i right click mouse button around 5-10 times in a second when i click stylus s-pen button.

[image]

[image]

Main objective i am trying to achieve, is , i wished to use samsung s-pen 's button for right mouse click and use it on Krita painting app's popup palette.

As like you see pictures , button event trigger multiple times in terminal and in krita popup palette open and close many times in a second.

I need help to figure this out. Thanks

Comment: You have to "de-bounce" the input.  So either ignore further events while you are processing the click. Or require a minimum threshold between clicks.. or both.

Comment: what is reason the code fired many times ?

Comment: Assuming no bugs (like linking up listener multiple times), then it's just hardware vagaries (or faulty hardware)...  You don't normally notice it because well designed software ignores the subsequents (perhaps by putting up a blocker/wait cursor until it's done what it needs, or the second right click is say meaningless once the popup is up).  In a drawing tool, however, they want to do everything you do...

Comment: Some frameworks you need to "consume" the event when done - so it doesn't propagate further / get processed by something else - does what you're using need you to do that?